# how to get data from Android phone internal memory in downloading or recovery mode

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

My Yotaphone 2 started to boot loop (can not finish booting). I can only reach "Downloading mode"
or Android system recovery with options:

- "reboot system now"
- "apply update from ADB"
- "wipe data/factory reset"
- "wipe cache partirtion"
- "reboot to bootloader"
- "power down"
- "view recovery log"

reboot or wipe cache partition didn't help.

I tried "ADB devices" but it can't see the phone and shows only  "List of devices attached" (downloading or recovery modes).

The Windows_7 can see "Androd bootloader interface" in downloading mode or "Linux file-CD Gadged USB Device" in the boot loop state.

I was also unsuccessfil with the "go-mtpfs" to reach MTP file transfer in Linux.

Before I do the factory reset I would like to save photos and some datas.

Is there any other way how to save datas from the Android phone with boot loop problem?

Comment: if your bootloader is unlocked you can *'fastboot boot twrp.img'* custom recovery and decrypt your files

Answer (score 0):

after trying (four different ROM) and spending many hours with

- fastboot boot boot.img  (some finished OK but still boot loop)
- fastboot boot system.img (finished with errors and still boot loop)

I gave up trying to save datas and did "wipe data/factory reset".
The mobile phone started after few minutes and works, unfortunately without my photos a files.